# Customise array of object to string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, object

Hi now i'm working on some laravel generator stuff to provide user to user admin panel for generator. [laravel manthra](https://github.com/nicoaudy/laravelmanthra). i have some issue when to merging and custom array to string. I have array like this :

```php
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "name"
    "type" => "string"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "slug"
    "type" => "string"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "name" => "content"
    "type" => "text"
  ]
]
```

i want merge array object with `#` separator, each object should separates with `;`. Result something like this

```php
name#string;slug#string;content#text;
```

how can i achieve this, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Could you try this**

```
$merge = '';
foreach ($arrays as $array)
{
 $merge .= $array->name.'#'.$array->type.';';
}
```

I don't know the name of your array but just change it. By the way this is on php or laravel

Hope it helps!